# Do Virtual Directories in shared hosting conflict with stuff in wwwroot?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, hosting, virtual-directory

I have an asp.net mvc application, phpBB forum and asp.net webservice that I want them all in the same wwwroot.

My shared hosting allows virtual directories so I went a head and made one. It made the directory and some web.config in it.

I then uploaded my asp.net webservice and overrode the web.config that was in virtual directory with the one from the webservice.

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Stack Trace:

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +43
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +127
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +142
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +57
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
   System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler..ctor(VirtualDirectory vdir) +163
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +53
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(VirtualDirectory vdir, VirtualPath virtualDir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +175
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +83
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +261
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +101
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +83
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath) +10
   System.Web.UI.WebServiceParser.GetCompiledType(String inputFile, HttpContext context) +43
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +180
   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +47
   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +307
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

So I have no clue why it wants the MVC .dll is it mad because I deleted the default web.config in the virtual directory?

Ok I have this

```
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </location>
```

but I get this

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: <location> sections are allowed only within <configuration> sections.

Source Error:

Line 68:             during development.
Line 69:     -->
Line 70:        <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
Line 71:            <compilation debug="true">
Line 72:                <assemblies>
```

I also tried this

```
<configuration>
  <location path="."  inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <configSections>
```

So it wants configSections first but I am not sure where to move it

```
 Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element.

Source Error:

Line 10: <configuration>
Line 11:   <location path="."  inheritInChildApplications="false">
Line 12:    <configSections>
Line 13:        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
Line 14:            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put the MVC dlls in your /bin folder?

Sometimes it will work locally because the MVC bins are in the GAC, but they may not be in the GAC on the server.

ETA:

Sounds like maybe your webservice virtual is inheriting settings from the main web.  You probably have something like this in your main web.config:

```
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Try surrounding that (or the whole `<system.web>` section) with this:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
....
</location>
```

More info [here](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2008/03/Prevent-ASPNET-webconfig-inheritance-and-inheritInChildApplications-attribute.aspx)

Comment: Well I have in my wwwroot where my asp.net mvc application lives has the bin folder and it contains the mvc.dll and it loads up just fine. The problem is my virtual directory has my asp.net webservice what is not an asp.net mvc application so it only has my webservice.dll in the bin folder. Yet it is asking for the mvc.dll what makes no sense. If I put the webservice in the wwwroot by itself(so not mvc stuff) it works fine.

Comment: I just tried and I have to in my virtual directory every bin that I use even if my application does not use it. It makes no sense.

Comment: hmm I think it might be working but I notice by doing this it kills the debugger in Vs2008. If I have this line in my web.config I cannot debug anymore. I take it out and I can debug.

Comment: @chobo2 - That's probably because the `<compilation debug="true">` is not inherited by the webservice sub-web anymore.  Try putting a web.config file in that virtual directory and add make sure it has that section in it (minus the MVC dll references of course)

Comment: Hi the webservice has its own web.config and has that line in it. I think it still does debugging on the webserivce. I am talking about my asp.net mvc application and it's web.config(so the root web.config). When I have that line it it I lose the deubugger.

Comment: @chobo2 - Did you put the <location> line around the whole <system.web> section rather than just the <compilation> section?  Now that I think about it, it may not be valid to put it just around the <configuration> section (but I'm not 100% sure on that)

Answer (score 0):

Your web.config file is looking for a MVC file, remove this line from your web.config

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Thanks

[ReliableSite.Net](http://www.reliablesite.net/)

Comment: Yep it needs to be there otherwise my asp.net mvc  app won't work.

Comment: Well then place the MVC dll in the bin folder.